# How to Install older Java version (ie.. v10) on 18.04

Tags: apt, java, ppa

On Ubuntu 18.04, I'm having an issue with Java 11 intermittently locking up my computer (ie.. need to do a hard-reset) when using the Stanford CoreNLP server software package.  I've downgraded to java 8 and, at least so far, haven't seen the issue.  I downgraded all the way to v8 because it didn't appear that v9 or v10 were available from the ppa.  For instance I did...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java10-installer
```

and received the message

```
E: Package 'oracle-java10-installer' has no installation candidate
```

The above works for 11, so it looks like they've taken away versions 9 and 10.  Is there a way I can install these older packages so I don't have to go all the way back to v8?  Is there's place where these "historical" versions are kept?  I've looked but haven't found them.

In part I'd like to do this to help narrow down the java version where the issue is coming from so maybe a fix can be found.

Comment: Just for your reference: Java 9 and 10 were non-LTS version of Java which reached their respective end of life. Java 8 and 11 are LTS versions. So, it is better to use these versions.